# Magento randomly crashes

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mariadb, magento

I've got an Ubuntu Server 12.04 with MariaDB and PHP 5.4.35

The server currently hosts 60+ small WordPress sites, of wich only 3-4 got high traffic.

Everything was working fine for the past 2 year.

Two weeks ago I've had to "import" an existing Magento website from another hosting company, so I've uploaded the files and the db inside MariaDB, and after editing the config file, the site showed correctly.

But after 2-3 days, it randomly crashes. By crash I mean that trying to access the website, Chrome responds with `E_CONN_RESET` and nothing is in the logs.

The only thing I could find is on the MariaDB logs:

```
151004 10:47:10 [Warning] Aborted connection 233756 to db: 'nhav' user: 'nhav' host: 'localhost' (Unknown error)
```

By doing `service apache2 reload` the site starts working again.

What can I do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by disabling APC with `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off
```

Apparently I'm not the only one having this kind of problem with apc, and also the database was not the issue.